# Create dict from string in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

In my Python program, I have a string of format:

```
'name': 'Salman','age': '25', 'access': 'R', 'id': '00125'
```

I want to convert it to type dict so that I can query like `dict["name"]` to get `"Salman"` printed.

Comment: Write a regular expression or split it by comma and trim or try to have the string as json in first place. Show us what you've tried till now.

Comment: Possible duplicate with : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

mystr = "'name': 'Salman','age': '25', 'access': 'R', 'id': '00125'"

d = ast.literal_eval('{'+mystr+'}')

# {'access': 'R', 'age': '25', 'id': '00125', 'name': 'Salman'}

d['access']  # 'R'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a neat solution using comprehensions

```
s = "'name': 'Salman','age': '25', 'access': 'R', 'id': '00125'"
d = dict([i.strip().replace("'", "") for i in kv.split(':')] for kv in s.split(","))
# d == {'access': 'R', 'age': '25', 'id': '00125', 'name': 'Salman'}
```

Answer (score 0):

first split the string by ":" and "," and store it in a list.
then iterate from 0 to len(list)-2: mydict[list[i]] = list[i+1]